# Angular 2 Router not navigating properly for query parameters

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am implementing login functionality for my Angular app.
When a user tries to login I route them to the login component like so:

```
this.router.navigate(['login'], {
  queryParams: {
    return: this.url
  }
});
```

When they login in, it returns them to the page where they were on.

This works fine for locations in the app like:

```
http://localhost:4200/category/Americana
```

When I go to the login page the URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:4200/login?return=%2Fcategory%2FAmericana
```

And it returns properly to:

```
http://localhost:4200/category/Americana
```

However, when I try to login from a route with a query parameter like so:

```
http://localhost:4200/categories/0?nav=All
```

The login page looks like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/login?return=%2Fcategories%2F0%3Fnav%3DAll
```

But the return page it goes to looks like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/categories/0%3Fnav%3DAll
```

And therefore when I try and get the parameters from the route, they are blank, becuase it has been mashed up in the route navigation.

How do i get the return functionality working for query parameters? Thanks - I'm new to this routing stuff - go easy on me :)

Comment: Try using "this.router.navigateByUrl(...)" on the login redirect

Comment: Can you post the routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by doing as suggested by the comment of J. Pinxter, using

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('categories/0?nav=All')
```